# Single Sign On (SSO) for asp.net 4.0 apps with one login application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, single-sign-on

this question is probably strange for the most of you but it's a very simple problem. I've more and less 10 applications that need to have a SSO solution. We succeeded in doing everything using machinekey but now the need is to create a central login application (with basically the login form and password retrieval box) which is the landing page to users trying to enter one of the app without authenticating first.

The problem is that if I put the absolute loginurl in the applications' web.config (e.g. instead of ~/login.aspx i put http://login.myapp.com/) I'm successfully redirected but the passed ReturnUrl is not absolute but relative and so I cannot get back to the "calling" application.

Any idea in how to solve this?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: We'd have to see the code which is performing the redirection to begin to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Hi @Chris. Here is the web.config of the two apps:

LOGIN APPLICATION WEB.CONFIG
`<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="default.aspx"
        enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
        path="/"
        domain=".mydomain.me"
        timeout="30" />
</authentication>`


APPLICATION WEB.CONFIG
`<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="http://login.mydomain.me/"
        enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
        path="/"
        domain=".mydomain.me"
        timeout="30" />
</authentication>`

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config try setting the [enableCrossAppRedirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.enablecrossappredirects.aspx) attribute to true;

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms .... enableCrossAppRedirects = "true" ....>
            </forms>
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This does open you up to redirect attacks however ...

Comment: Hi @blowdart and thanks for your reply. I already tried with enableCrossAppRedirects but nothing seems changed. The ReturnUrl is always the same (relative, not absolute).